# No chance to run drush on php 5.3.2?

Tags: drush

I have php 5.3.2 installed, which I need for Plesk11 on a virtual Server. Unfortunately drush needs 5.3.3. Is there no way to run it with 5.3.2?

Otherwise I have to compile a second php especially for drush, but I can't find any requirements.